# EF6 Migration Mysql Connector 6.9 success with collection latin1_swedish_ci but error with utf8 or utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6, migration

[image]
Hello, I trying genereted database using EF6.1.3 with Migration and 
MySql(connector **6.9**) version 5.7. But i receive a error when try generate database. The error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes.
My Database collection: **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** = the table __migrations and ForenKeys... doens't generated    ---- Why??
My Database collection: **utf8_unicode_c**i = the table __migrations and ForenKeys... doens't generated    ---- Why??
My Database collection: **atin1_swedish_ci**i = the table __migrations ... success!
I Whant work with UTF8MB4_unicode_ci
My Video in **português** trying explain : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJQqcZzF9ik (Check the collation changes)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at your varchar columns and make sure they get 191 for max length

Comment: why? varchar is 255

Comment: Nope, not in utf8mb4 that uses one more byte to encode information.
Check Step 4 here : https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4